# Проблема с кодировками на сайта

Tags: requests, beautiful-soup

Решил я получать данные от гугл по зараженным, но  не  тут то было. Хотя у них указана кодировка UTF-8 на странице, но видимо это не совсем так. Что делать, даже не знаю. Encode, decode разные уже пробовал. Онлайн кодировщики все выдают разные кодировки, а некоторые вапще отказываются определять кодировку текста.
Вот мой код, может я делаю что то не так.

```
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0"}

page_link = "https://google.com/covid19-map/?hl=ru"
page_response = requests.get(page_link, headers = headers)
print(page_response.content)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "lxml")
content_table = page_content.find("table",{"class": "SAGQRd"})
tbody = content_table.find("tbody")
content = tbody.findAll("tr")
for i in content:
    sub_content = i.findAll("td")
    a = 0
    while a < 5:
        if a == 0:
            print("\n\n" + str(sub_content[a].find("span")))
        else:
            newtext = (sub_content[a].getText()).replace(chr(160), ",")
            print(newtext)
        a = a + 1
```

Проблема чаще всего в span блоках (такая же ситуация на сайте 2gis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была там, где я этого сам не ожидал. Я использовал для запуска файла git bash, там кодировка по умолчанию другая. Если запускать через powershell или в linux, то все нормально. В таком случае обрабатывать nbsp тоже не нужно, так что необходимость в коде

```
.replace(chr(160), ",")
```

тоже отпадает